# Ctypes reading modified array

Tags: python, c, ctypes

These are the C files:

**addone.h**

```
#ifndef __ADDONE
#define __ADDONE
void  addone(float *in_data, int size);
#endif
```

**addone.c**

```
void addone(float *in_data, int size)
{
  int i = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    in_data[i] = in_data[i] + 1;
  }
}
```

And I am trying to use this function with Ctypes:

```
import ctypes
libaddone = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libaddone.so")
libaddone.addone.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float), ctypes.c_int)
a = [1,2,3]
array_type = ctypes.c_float * 3
libaddone.addone(array_type(*a), ctypes.c_int(3))
print a
```

But I am getting the same result for `a` : `[1,2,3]`

What am I doing wrong while reading the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*a` in Python already loses track of the original array; instead it makes a new immutable *tuple* object of the elements of array, and this tuple is passed as the positional arguments to the `array_type` object constructor, which makes yet *another*, mutable array object. And it is this object that gets modified in `addone`.

---

You can try

```
import ctypes
libaddone = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("libaddone.so")
libaddone.addone.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float), ctypes.c_int)
a = [1,2,3]
array_type = ctypes.c_float * 3
my_array = array_type(*a)
libaddone.addone(my_array, ctypes.c_int(3))
print(list(my_array))
```